# Adding addSbtPlugin("org.xerial.sbt" % "sbt-sonatype" % "1.1") to my project fails with "Unresolved Dependencies"

Tags: sbt, sonatype

I am trying to publish my [SBT project](https://github.com/shafiquejamal/richstat) to mvnrepository. I am following the directions at these links:

http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Using-Sonatype.html, and 
https://github.com/xerial/sbt-pack

When I add the xerial sbt-sonatype plugin to my `build.sbt` file:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.xerial.sbt" % "sbt-sonatype" % "1.1")
```

The compiler gives me the following error:

```
UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES

org.xerial.sbt#sbt-sonatype;1.1 not found

Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      org.xerial.sbt:sbt-sonatype:1.1 (scalaVersion=2.11, sbtVersion=0.13)
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      org.xerial.sbt:sbt-sonatype:1.1 (scalaVersion=2.11, sbtVersion=0.13) (/richstat/build.sbt#L56-57)
[warn]        +- com.github.shafiquejamal:richstat_2.11:0.0.1
```

My SBT version is 0.13, and I am using Scala 2.11. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add plugins in `project/plugins.sbt`, because plugins are dependencies of the *meta-project*, not your library/application.

Check sbt documentation: [Using Plugins](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Using-Plugins.html).

Also regarding sbt version and Scala version: there is Scala version used to compile your project's code (2.11 in your case), and there is Scala version used by sbt itself. The latter is determined by the sbt version: sbt-0.13 uses Scala 2.10, sbt-1.0 uses Scala 2.12.

P.S. I recommend you updating to sbt-1.0.2: just change the version in `project/build.properties` and use sbt-sonatype 2.0.

Comment: By the way, I see now that you followed the instructions you referenced and I think they just have a typo (submitted a [fix](https://github.com/sbt/website/pull/523)).

Comment: Thanks - this works. Yes, I was following the directions exactly as given. This link: `https://github.com/xerial/sbt-sonatype` actually has the correct path for the plugin.

Comment: Also, `addSbtPlugin("org.xerial.sbt" % "sbt-sonatype" % "1.1") ` should instead be `addSbtPlugin("org.xerial.sbt" % "sbt-sonatype" % "2.3")` (or 2.1, or 2.2 - the list of versions can be found here: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/xerial/sbt/sbt-sonatype_2.12_1.0/)